# Netbeans Java - Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project Sintetizee:

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Always that i try run my file, this error appears

`Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project Sintetizee: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]`

My code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArrayListTeste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> Aluno = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        Aluno.add(5, "Mikael");

    }
}
```

```
public class Vetor {
    private Aluno[] A;
    private int capacity;
    private int size;
    
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (size==0) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
    public Aluno get(int i) throws Exception {
        if(isEmpty()) throw new Exception ("Lista está vazia!");
        if (i>=size()) throw new Exception ("Posição não existe!");
        return A[i];
    }
    public void set(int i, Aluno n) throws Exception {
        if(isEmpty()) throw new Exception ("Lista está vazia!");
        if (i>=size()) throw new Exception ("Posição não existe!");
        A[i]=n;
    }
    public void locPlace (Aluno n) throws Exception {
        if (size==0)
            add(0,n);
        else
            for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
                if (n.getCodigo()>=A[i].getCodigo()){
                    add(i,n);
                    break;
                }
    }
    public void add(int i, Aluno n) throws Exception {
        if (size==A.length)
            size--;
        for (int j=size-1;j>=i;j--){
            A[j+1]=A[j];
            A[i]=n;
            size++;
        }
    }
    public void remove(int i) throws Exception {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new Exception ("Lista esta vazia!");
        if (i>=size) throw new Exception ("Posição está invalida!");
        for(int j=i;j<=size;j++)
            A[j]=A[j+1];
        size--;
    }
    public int search (Aluno n) {
        for (int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
            if (A[i].getNome().equals(n.getNome()))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I tried some solutions, like reinstall maven or mvn clean install (but build failure) on cmd. When I didn't used ArrayList or Vetor, my code worked. My Maven version is 3.6.3 and its working. Netbeans 12.0 and i already reinstalled as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sintetizee</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I press F6 to run my file ArrayListTeste and that error appears. When I used "mvn clean install" on my project with pom.xml, the build failure.

Comment: You have posted more or less everything but the important part the pom.xml you haven't... and the commands you are using to execute it... BTW.: Which java version do you use?

Comment: I edit my post and put it pom.xml. My Java version is 15.0.2 on my CMD. But when I install Netbeans, i selected JDK 1.8.0_111 because my Netbeans didn't open with 15.0.2. The screen went white and nothing happen